# Positioning the drop down menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

Hi Please help me on this issue.

Issue: dropdown values of the menu is shown in other menu (it is not in-line with menu). 
       Example: Dropdown values of Home menu is Home-1, Home-2, Home-3  and it will shown under National parties menu. How can I show appropriately under the right menu
Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/shrikanth/Sv79m/

```
  <div id="menu">
  <ul>
      < li><a href="index.html">Home</a><ul>
       <li><a href="index.html">Home-1</a></li>
       <li><a href="aboutus.html">Home-2</a></li>
       <li><a href="services.html">Home-3</a></li>
        </ul></li>
       <li ><a href="aboutus.html">National Parties<ul>
              <li><a href="index.html">BJP</a></li>
              <li><a href="aboutus.html">Congress</a></li>
              <li><a href="services.html">CPM</a></li>
      </ul></a></li>
      <li><a href="services.html">Services<ul>
       <li><a href="index.html">TV</a></li>
       <li><a href="aboutus.html">Cell</a></li>
       <li><a href="services.html">Radio</a></li>
        </ul></a></li>
        <li>Contact Us
         <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html">India</a></li>
          <li><a href="aboutus.html">USA</a></li>
          <li><a href="services.html">SAUS</a></li>
         </ul>

        </li>
         </ul>
            </div>
```

CSS

```
     #menu {
     width: 550px;
     height: 35px;
     font-size: 16px;
     font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
     font-weight: bold;
     text-align: center;
     text-shadow: 1px 2px 1px #333333;
     background-color: #8AD9FF;
     border-radius: 8px;
     }


    #menu ul {
    height: auto;
    padding: 8px 0px;
     margin: 0px;
       }

         #menu li { 
         display: inline; 
         padding: 20px; 
         }

            #menu ul li a {
            text-decoration: none;
             color: #00F;
             padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
             }


            #menu a:hover {
             color: #F90;
          background-color: #FFF;
           }




               #menu ul li ul{
                 display:none;
             position:absolute;
             top:31px;
           background-color:red;



                   }



          #menu ul li:hover ul{


            display:inline-block;
           height:auto;
            width:135px;




          }

            #menu  ul  li ul:before{



             content: '';

              border-color: transparent transparent red transparent;

              border-style: solid;

                 border-width: 10px;  /* The border on the drop down box  */ 

              position: absolute;

               top: -20px;

                   left: 37%;

                  margin-left:10px;

                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Sv79m/1/

Give #menu li a position of relative:

```
#menu li { 
display: inline; 
padding: 20px;     
position:relative;
}
```

Adjust a little the absolute positioning with left:0 :

```
#menu ul li ul{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:51px;
    background-color:red;
    left:0;
    }
```

Edit:

Also, to solve the overlapping links, add this:

```
#menu ul li ul li{
    display:block;
    padding:5px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Sv79m/2/

Also, you had some unclosed  tags, I closed them and now it's much better:

http://jsfiddle.net/Sv79m/3/

```
<a href="aboutus.html">National Parties<ul>
                                      ^^CLOSE ME!
```

Answer (score 0):

It's all down to the positioning of the containing element. If you use position: relative; it allows you to position elements absolutely inside of it.

Here's a tutorial on creating a dropdown navigation, it explains about the positioning and structure. This should help - [CSS 3 navigation menu](http://www.adam-bray.com/blog/91/Easy+HTML+5+&+CSS+3+Navigation+Menu/)

Comment: Thanks Adamb89. It has been resolved just by adding left:0 in css as indicated in the above answer. Thanks again